# Как добавить свои сниппеты (пользовательские фрагменты) в Emmet в VSCode (VSCodium)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, emmet, vscodium

Всем привет!
Я хочу добавить свои сниппеты (пользовательские фрагменты) в Emmet. Сделал всё по [официальной инструкции](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) - в emmet.extensionsPath указал полный путь к файлу snippets.json

> /home/.config/VSCodium/User/profiles/-3c58343f/emmet/snippets.json

Содержание файла:

```
{
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
            "div": "<div class=\"${1}\">${2}</div>",
            "img": "<img src=\"${1}\" alt=\"${2}\" class=\"${3}\">",
            "source": "<source srcset=\"${1}\" class=\"${2}\">",
            "time": "<time class=\"${1}\" datetime=\"${2}\">"
        }
    }
}
```

При всём этом мои сокращения в HTML всё равно не отображаются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Чтобы свои сниппеты применялись, нужно в emmet.extensionsPath указывать путь только ДО каталога с файлом snippets.json

Правильный вариант:

> /home/.config/VSCodium/User/profiles/-3c58343f/emmet

В каталоге "emmet" уже находится сам файл snippets.json со своими сниппетами.